# JavaScript display data on html via localhost

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program related to JavaScript. I have 1 UDP server and 1 UDP client, now the client can send the data to server and display the data through browser. To show the result, first I will open a terminal then type" node udpserver.js". After that I will open a browser and type "localhost:portnumber" then the result (text) will shown. However, I cannot control where the text display. Also I want to cut it into 2 frames (Left and Right). So I can display the data simultaneously in left and right. How can I do that? Thanks so much.

Here is the udpserver.js:

```
// JavaScript Document

//server.js

console.log("test ok");

var PORT = 1234;

var HOST = 'localhost';


var http = require('http');
    var dgram = require('dgram');
    var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

    //As soon as the server is ready to receive messages, handle it with this handler
    server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
    });

    var mymes;


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
        //print out the message
        mymes = message;
        console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);
        res.write('message:'+mymes+"\n");
        //prepare a response
        var okBuffer = new Buffer("OK " + message);
        server.send(okBuffer, 0, okBuffer.length, remote.port, remote.address, function(err, bytes){
            if (err){
                throw err;
            }
        //print out to the server's console that we've successfully sent the response to the client
        //console.log("OK sent to client");

        this.type = 'text/html';
        });
    });


}).listen(PORT);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1234');

    server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

Comment: Pls share your related code.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're using NodeJS. Try some [tutorials](https://nodejs.org/documentation/tutorials/)

Comment: You should just display the data in HTML.

Comment: How can I connect html file and javascript file? since I need to use "node udpserver.js" to get the data. Thanks